# Is the Singleton Design Pattern good or bad practice for banking application in c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, singleton

Is the Singleton Design Pattern good or bad practice  for banking application in c# ?
Any problem with performance and security?

Answer (score 1):

Singleton Design Patterns are used when you don't want to create more than one object of a class.

So it really depends on what you want to do, and what functionality you are trying to implement.

For the database connection you can use the singleton design pattern. Also for the transactions you may want to create a thread safe Singleton design pattern.

But as a whole, it cannot be said that if Singleton is a good or bad practice for Banking Service.

Comment: Since the question is tagges ASP.NET, singleton could do a lot of harm when used for database connections.